# error when running app on external device

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\HOME\AndroidStudioProjects\Resturant_local2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\2e270dbe94502e9cd793d1e7932032d2\kernel_snapshot.d
lib/my%20First%20app/cart%20controller.dart:1:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:js_interop' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:js_interop';
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:js_interop' is imported through these packages:

    package:resturant_local2 => dart:js_interop

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    package:resturant_local2/main.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/home.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/Cart%20Total.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/Third%20Page.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/cart%20controller.dart => dart:js_interop
    package:resturant_local2/main.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/home.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/Cart%20Total.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/cart%20controller.dart => dart:js_interop
    package:resturant_local2/main.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/home.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/Third%20Page.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/cart%20controller.dart => dart:js_interop
    package:resturant_local2/main.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/home.dart => package:resturant_local2/my%20First%20app/cart%20controller.dart => dart:js_interop
```

This the error i always encounter when trying to run my app on an external device on android studio.

I tried using flutter clean or flutter upgrade and everything just does not seem to work

Comment: remove `dart:js_interop` import from your project.

Comment: i did that and it did not work